# Problems making ajax call for json data from Statistics Sweden public API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, opendata

Hoping to get help identifying problem with my ajax call to Statistics Sweden (SCB).
[SCB API instructions are here](http://www.scb.se/Grupp/OmSCB/API/API-description.pdf)

I can successfully get the table metadata (step 4.3 in instructions) with below call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/BE/BE0401/BE0401B",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText)
    }
});
```

But, I receive 404 error not found, when I trying below to query the table with a POST request.
(example taken from step 4.4 in instructions - bottom half of page 7 of PDF)

Or if I try with a GET request, I just get get the table metadata and no results

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/BE/BE0401/BE0401B/BefProgFoddaMedel15",
    data: {
        "query": 
           [{"code":"Fodelseland", "selection":{"filter":"item",
           "values":["010","020"]}},
           {"code":"Alder", "selection":{"filter":"all", "values":["*"]}},
           {"code":"Tid", "selection":{ "filter":"top", "values":["3"]}}],
         "response": {"format":"json"}
    },
    type: "POST",  // GET returns only table metadata
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText)
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
*added that also tried with GET request but only returns table metadata and not statistics*

**SOLUTION**
Call JSON.stringify on the query data before posting.
Code posted below by Petros Likidis

Comment: your data format is wrong try proper as given step in 4.3 in pdf

Comment: @MudassarZahid can you expand on your answer with example of correct ajax call?  Your answer is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in javascript but I have had the same problem. I solved it by converting the json query (the post data) as a string by calling JSON.stringify see

http://jsbin.com/punaveteke/edit?js,console,output

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/BE/BE0401/BE0401B/BefProgFoddaMedel15",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "query": [{
                "code": "Fodelseland",
                "selection": {
                    "filter": "item",
                    "values": ["010", "020"]
                }
            }, {
                "code": "Alder",
                "selection": {
                    "filter": "all",
                    "values": ["*"]
                }
            }, {
                "code": "Tid",
                "selection": {
                    "filter": "top",
                    "values": ["3"]
                }
            }],
            "response": {
                "format": "json"
            }
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.statusText)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.  
I tried it with a few other queries and works just fine now.   
I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation appears to be wrong. If you run it as a `GET` request (rather than `POST`), it returns results.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/BE/BE0401/BE0401B/BefProgFoddaMedel15",
data: {
    "query": 
       [{"code":"Fodelseland", "selection":{"filter":"item",
       "values":["010","020"]}},
       {"code":"Alder", "selection":{"filter":"all", "values":["*"]}},
       {"code":"Tid", "selection":{ "filter":"top", "values":["3"]}}],
     "response": {"format":"json"}
},
type: "GET",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
},
error: function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.statusText)
}
});
```

Really, the API should have returned a "405 (Method Not Allowed)" error, which would have given you a better clue as to why the request was failing. The resource isn't missing (as a 404 implies), simply you have to access it via a different method.

Might be worth highlighting to the maintainers of the API that their documentation is erroneous and that their API returns unhelpful errors.

Comment: The GET request still just returns metadata for the table, rather than the Query results, I believe?

It returns an object with the table title "Births by country of birth, age, observations and year".   Then the list of the variables : "country of birth", "age, "births", and "year".  And each variable lists all the available fields.   But unfortunately no data.

Comment: I wouldn't like to comment - I don't know what exact content should be expected. But it fixes the 404 error, as per the stated question. If doing a POST ought to return different values, yet you get a 404, then either the documentation is wrong in a different way, or the API implementation is broken. Either way, you should query it with the maintainers. Have you tried varying the query parameters (maybe with something simpler?) to see if you get a result?

Comment: Yes I've done several simple queries.   They actually have a website where you can search for data and then it will generate the API query for you.  Example on this page.   
http://www.statistikdatabasen.scb.se/pxweb/en/ssd/START__BE__BE0101__BE0101A/BefolkningNy/table/tableViewLayout1/?rxid=82f98882-d1b8-4a2c-90ca-2483b1bc4e5f
Click on the bottom link "API for this table".


But as you suggested, I will contact them.  Maybe they have made some changes.    

Thanks for checking to that there doesn't appear to be anything glaringly wrong with my syntax.